# How to pass $scope value to custom filter in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array show below,

$scope.selectionCat = ['1','3','4']

In HTML am calling like

<div dir-paginate="item in items | filterForCat:this">

Custom filter

```
.filter('filterForCat', function () {
  return function (item, scope) {
    return (scope.selectionCat.indexOf(item.category_id.id) !== -1);
  };
})
```

When am trying to read'scope.selectionCat' values am getting error like 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'

Can i get any help to solve this?

Comment: `category_id` is undefined.  Have you verified that it exists on `item`?

Comment: yes i have verified..  when i console it am getting an array of objects..

Comment: There is no such thing as `this` in a template. Don't pass the scope. Pass selectionCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you want to filter items which's id is included by `scope.selectionCat`, as commented by @JB Nizet, you should not pass scope(this) to filters which you **can** but should **avoid** using filter this way, and you have to return **filter result** not just true/false of an expression.

Also for the error you are facing will be solved by `Array.filter` for if there's no data in items, the callback of `Array.filter` won't be executed.

Here you filter can be written like below

```
.filter('filterForCat', function () {
  return function (items, selectionVat) {
    return items.filter(function(item) {
      return selectionCat.indexOf(item.category_id.id) !== -1
    });
  };
})
```